# i want to use a loop for Jquery function

Tags: jquery, html

the overlap class is hidden.so by clicking over a tag the overlap div is shown..I have used the following script :
     $( "#client-1 a" ).click(function() {  $( "#client-1 .overlap" ).show(600);  });
     $( "#client-2 a" ).click(function() {  $( "#client-2 .overlap" ).show(600);  });
  this script works fine.I want to use a var instead of static digit and by clicking on any a tag the specific div of that a tag must be shown ....
    textthis is overlap div
    textthis is overlap

Comment: Yes, of course it is. Where did you get stuck?

Comment: i want to use a var instead of '#client-9'...something like #client-i...

Comment: i want to use a loop ..

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var id = "";
var i;

for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{ 
    id = "#client-" + i;
    $(id + " a").click(function() { $(id + " .overlap").show(600); });
}
```

Comment: Thanks,But it works only one time.page is static html page and element is a list

Comment: You'll have to specify more clearly what you want. At this moment this is not very clear to others.